# Import the android music application into an Eclipse workpace

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I downloaded android [music sources](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music) to learn from. Essentially, I want to explore it in Eclipse. I've tried importing android project - it doesn't seem to find any projects in the folder which obviously contains one. When I had tried to new project with existing source it said `The application name is shown in the PlayStore, as well in the Manage Application` list in Settings.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project exists, but it is not an Eclipse project. you shouldn't import it, you should do :

`New project > Android > Android project from from existing code` and point to your folder